# JAVA Stopping user scanner by entering value

Tags: java

I am in my joureny of learning ( udemy right now ) and I got a mission to code an grocerylist (ArrayList)
and let the user choose between some option :
adding item
remove item
show list
and more.

I decided when the user want to adding an item it will be on loop so he will add much items as he like to and will not get back to the main menu and then chose "adding item" again.

so it's look like this:

```
public static void addItem() {
    System.out.println("Which item would you like to add?");
    System.out.println("*** Type n when you done ***");
    boolean exit = false;
    while (!exit) {
        String item = in.next();
        groceryList.addItem(item);
        if(item.equals("n")) {
            exit = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Thats was my only idea to stop the loop.
so now "n" is counting as an item so I did something like that :

btw thats the addItem function from the GroceryList class:

```
   public void addItem(String item) {
    groceryList.add(item);
        if(groceryList.contains("n")){
          groceryList.remove(groceryList.size()-1);
 }
}
```

so yo can see here it's removing "n" from the list (n was the last one)

I am sure that there is much more useful way of doing this (stopping the loop). So thats why I need your help.

Comment: IMO more intuitive way would be moving `groceryList.addItem(item);` to `else` branch like `if(item.equals("n")) { exit = true; } else { groceryList.addItem(item); }`. This way you wouldn't add `n` to list so you wouldn't need to handle it there.

Comment: How could I not think about that -.-
thank you! problem solved ;)

Comment: I think you don't need to GroceryList class. Simply initialize `List<String> groceryList` in the main class. You can use `continue;` keyword for the skip current iteration in the while loop so you return to main menu in the program.

Answer (score 1):

In the addItem, before the add, you can check what is the value.
If the value is "n", you do not add it.
You can even make the method addItem return a boolean instead of nothing (void) telling you if the item was succesfully added or not. If not, you end the loop.

Comment: There is any other ways finishing this loop instead typing "n" ? its look a little bit stupid